# add where diffrence >0 in .net api using mongodb

Tags: .net, mongodb, asp.net-core, aggregation-framework, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a class product

```
public class Product
    {
        [BsonId]
        public Object Id { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("sku")]
        public string Sku { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("price")]
        public double Price { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("store")]
        public int Store { get; set; }
    }
```

and class buteer

```
 public class butter
    {

        public string Sku { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public double Maxprice { get; set; }

        public double MinPrice { get; set; }

        public double Diffrence { get; set; } // max -min
    }
```

I am make an API that take the data from product and return in in form of butter.
I am trying to add to my Api where diffrence > 0

```
public IEnumerable<butter> Get()
         {
            var result = _productCollection.AsQueryable()
                              .OrderByDescending(e => e.Price)
                              .GroupBy(e => e.Sku)
                              .Select(g => new butter
                              {
                                  Sku= g.First().Sku,
                                  Name=g.First().Name,
                                 Maxprice=g.Max(x=>x.Price),
                                  MinPrice=g.Min(x=>x.Price),
                                  Diffrence= (g.Max(x => x.Price)- g.Min(x => x.Price))
                              }
                               )
                              .ToList();
            return result;
        }
```

can you please help me add where diffrence >0 in my api code

Thank you

Comment: I tryied the following but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make an example which you can refer to. Because I don’t know the source of `_productCollection`. According to this model `Product`, I simulated some data in the database.

[image]

Since it is grouped by column **Sku**, it is used as the key for the next query. And `AsQueryable` should be changed to `ToList`. Here is the changed method to query.

```
public IEnumerable<butter> Get()
    {
        var result = _db.Products.ToList().OrderByDescending(e => e.Price).GroupBy(e => e.Sku).Select(x => new butter
                    {
                        Sku = x.Key,
                        Name = x.FirstOrDefault().Name,
                        Maxprice = x.Max(y => y.Price),
                        MinPrice = x.Min(y => y.Price),
                        Diffrence = x.Max(y => y.Price) - x.Min(y => y.Price)
                    }).Where(a => a.Diffrence > 0).ToList();
        return result;
    }
```

Because the highest price of `sku1` is equal to the lowest price, the **difference** will not be greater than 0. This is the result of the query.

[image]